# Play video stored on a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, video

I am trying to play a video that I have stored on a database using the BLOB format. I am using PHP to connect to the database. So far, this is the script that I have managed to come up with, what do I do to play the video?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video width="420" height="345" controls>
<source src="C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\AustralianOpen.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<?php
$username="root";
$password="mysql";
$database="test";
mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password) or die("Not able to connect to localhost");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select DB");

if(($result=mysql_query('Select data from media'))!=false)
{
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    print $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
} else
{
    die("Video no connecting");
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: SO is not here to write code for you. And as someone with as much SO experience as yourself, you should know that.

Comment: @Styphon I know but this is kind of an emergency.

Comment: So go to a job board and pay someone to do it for you. Google will provide you with plenty.

Answer (score 3):

Storing videos in a database is a pretty bad idea because of the file sizes involved. In this case, what's happening is `fetch()` transfers the whole content from the database buffer into PHP's memory, from which it is then `echo`'d. This means you need to fit the whole video into memory at once, and it needs to be transferred out to the web server before PHP's time limit is up. This may work for very small videos, but not for any video of a length worth watching.

Some databases like Postgres allow you to open a file handle to content in the database, which you could then dump directly to the client with `fpassthru`; that's more efficient memory wise, but will still require PHP to run the entire time the client is streaming the video. I'm also not sure whether MySQL supports that, never used it.

Last but not least, you can't just dump the video data in the middle of an HTML file.

Not to mention that for some reason you're mixing all sorts of database API syntax which doesn't belong together.

Overall, this is a bad approach. You should go back to serving video files stored on disk, which the web server can handle by itself.

Comment: So how do I deal with Live feeds? Like, a live feed video is continuously being stored on a db and then I need to display it. The thing is, I am storing it on a db because I need to rewind and show it without any lag. That's the problem. Thus the db.

Comment: MySQL is not the right tool for handling any sort of live video stream. There are streaming servers built specifically for that task, which will not use an RDBMS to store video data but other in-memory or on-disk buffers. Go back to the drawing board with this, it's not going to fly.

Comment: Okay. Will try again. :/